# Having trouble creating a simple custom route

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My goal is to remove "home" from any actions in that controller (see bold).

site.com/home/about
**site.com/about**

site.com/home/contact
**site.com/contact**

I created the following custom route that sits above the generic base route:

```
// Used to hide 'home' in the url
routes.MapRoute(
            "Home", // Route name
            "{action}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "home", action= "index"} // Parameter defaults
);
```

This *almost* does what I want.  I now get site.com/about, site.com/contact, etc.  However, I cannot use index for my other controllers.

site.com/person/create -> works like a charm.
site.com/person/ -> no good.

How can I fix this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two routes should work as expected:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "NoHomeRoute", // Route name
   "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Person", action= "Index"}, // Parameter defaults
   new { controller = @"person|admin|..." } // Parameter constraints
);
routes.MapRoute(
   "HomeRoute", // Route name
   "{action}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "home", action= "index"} // Parameter defaults
);
```

Since every application has a predefined set of controllers you can put all except *home* in the upper constraint and it will work. But if you create a new controller, remember to put it in as well. I've put in **person** for `PersonController` which you obviously have and also added **admin** for `AdminController` you probably don't have, but I needed to put in something to show you the pattern of adding your controllers.

If you're willing to play around with regular expressions, then you could maybe come up with a solution that excludes *home* instead of includes all except *home* the way that upper route definitions suggest.

### A revised negative constraint

I've checked MVC code and indeed you can define a future proof constraint on the first route definition this way:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "NoHomeRoute", // Route name
   "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Person", action= "Index"}, // Parameter defaults
   new { controller = @"(?!home).*" } // Parameter constraints
);
```

Why should this work? Because the line on `ProcessConstraint` method has these two lines at the end:

```
string pattern = "^(" + str + ")$";
return Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I can't get this to work when I try it. I was convinced it wasn't possible so would be very interesting to see it working.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the reply but unfortunately that did not work.  It behaves exactly the opposite of my attempt.  In other words, site.com/person works but not site.com/about (which is in the home controller).

Comment: @Beavis: I've updated my answer with a working solution. I should check how regular expression constraints work to know exactly why my previous attempt failed.

Comment: @Robert Thanks, that works.  The problem is I'm confused as to how/why it does.  Using your example, I can remove 'admin', yet admin still works.  Weird.

Comment: @Beavis: You can put in dummy controller constraints like **admin** and it will still work, since regular expression won't match them. But if you do have an `AdminController` and you remove **admin** out, it shouldn't work anymore. Unless you have a `HomeController.Admin` action method.

Comment: @Robert: That's the thing - I do have admin controller and I can remove admin from that list and it still works.

Comment: @Robert: Disregard my last message.  I goofed.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Beavis: Could you please also check my revised example that is more concise with future changes to your application whether it works or not.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3036/discussion-between-beavis-and-robert-koritnik)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Used to hide 'home' in the url
routes.MapRoute(
        "Home", // Route name
        "{action}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "home", action= "index"} // Parameter defaults);
```

should be the last route you register, otherwise site.com/person is interpreted as an action, since it will match that route first.